# Is AddSingleton guaranteed to run only once the factory in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

For instance, multiple requests are coming and each requests this singleton service from DI. With the service added using

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSingleton<TService>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Func<IServiceProvider, TService> implementationFactory)
    where TService : class
```

overload, would the factory method be guaranteed to run only once?

Comment: Do you have more than one server-instance? Then definitly Not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation isn't very specific, but you can assure that, within the context of the built-in container (MS.DI), the factory is guaranteed to be called at most once ***per IServiceProvider instance***.

Although I haven't got strong evidence to prove this claim, complete applications and frameworks are built around the assumption that this is guaranteed.

Please note the following:

- Although any 3rd-party adapter implementation might have less strong guarantees, one should expect the same behavior as the MS.DI.
- The definition of a Singleton is that it is "scoped" to the lifetime of a single container instance, i.e. the `IServiceProvider`. MS.DI follows this definition, which means that creating a new `IServiceProvider` based on the same `IServiceCollection` (e.g. by calling `BuildServiceProvider()`) will allow the factory delegate to be called again by that new `IServiceProvider`.

In an ASP.NET Core application (unless you override this), the framework manages the creation of the `ServiceCollection` and its resulting `ServiceProvider`. This means that there is only one `ServiceProvider` for the duration of the application, which means your Singleton factory delegate is called just once.

When you start calling `CreateServiceProvider()` manually, however, you will be creating extra `IServiceProvider` instances, and with it its own Singleton instances, which means extra calls to your Singleton factory delegates.

Comment: Can I safely expect that with normal injection method, the singleton service's constructor will only get executed once also?

Comment: @Nico, yes, you can safely assume this.